# Login page validation which is connected with mongoDB is working, but i want to redirect a query along with it after validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemon

I wrote a code which will verify the emailID and password, but while redirecting i want to pass in "user" => with => "_id". i'm new to mongoDB and don't have much experience with it, hope you can help me.
I'm learning it all by myself and would be great if you could help.

here is my code, which i wrote.

````
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  // let user;
  const user = req.query.u || 0;

  try {
    const check = await db
      .collection("userCredentials")
      .findOne({ email: req.body.emailId });
    if (check.pswd === req.body.psswd) {
      res.redirect("/home?u=" + user);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/signUp");
    }
  } catch {
    res.status(500).json(" User doesn't Exist");
  }
});```


i tried passing `user = db.collection("userCreditionals).ObjectId();`
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.